# Choose database based on the country

Tags: django, database, geoip

is there any possibility that we could select the database to which route a request of a user depending on the geolocalization of the client? Or the user country?

I've check some documentation of the dbrouters, but I am concerned that if a user travels to another country he is going to be routed to the wrong database.

Does anybody have this issue?

Comment: you want the user to always be routed to their 'home' database... or for them to be routed to the database of the country they're in currently?  and if the latter... why?

Comment: To the 'home'(if you are referring to the database they were registered)  database. Although in some cases their home database would be their country database. I don't want to do that but it's a requirement that is being asked.

Comment: so you don't want to do geolocalization, or at least only once when user registers, after that they always get the same db

Comment: so... you'd have the country saved as a field on the user and you need the db router to route based on user's country field: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21382032/202168